# 'System.Web.UI.Control.Controls' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, asp.net

What i am doing wrong? I extend LinkButton and i get this error

> Compilation Error Description: An
>   error occurred during the compilation
>   of a resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following
>   specific error details and modify your
>   source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0118:
>   'System.Web.UI.Control.Controls' is a
>   'property' but is used like a 'type'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1084:         Line 1085:
>   public void
>   @__DataBinding__control30(object
>   sender, System.EventArgs e) { Line
>   1086:
>   ConfirmButton.Controls.ConfirmLinkButton
>   dataBindingExpressionBuilderTarget;
>   Line 1087:
>   System.Web.UI.IDataItemContainer
>   Container; Line 1088:
>   dataBindingExpressionBuilderTarget =
>   ((ConfirmButton.Controls.ConfirmLinkButton)(sender));

This is C# code:

```
[Localizable(true)]
public string Message
{
    get { return ViewState["Message"] as string; }
    set { ViewState["Message"] = value; }
}

#region Overriden
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Message))
    {
        WebControlUtils.SetConfirmationMessage(Page, typeof (Page), this, Message, Page.IsAsyncPostBack(),
                                               CausesValidation);
    }
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}

#endregion
```

ASPX CODE:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ConfirmLinkButton ID="lnkBtnDelete" runat="server" Text="Odstrani" Message="Delete?"                                   

                CommandName="DeleteAgencie" Width="50"
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("idAgencies") %>'
                OnCommand="lnkBtnDelete_Command" CausesValidation="False"></asp:ConfirmLinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

C#

```
public static bool IsAsyncPostBack(this Page page)
{
    var result = false;
    var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page);
    if (scriptManager != null)
    {
        result = scriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack;
    }

    return result;
}




public static void SetConfirmationMessage(Page page, Type type, Control control, string message,
                                          bool isAsyncPostBack, bool causesValidation)
{
    string script = "SetConfirmation('" + control.ClientID + "','" + message + "'," +
                    causesValidation.ToString().ToLower() + ");";
    if (isAsyncPostBack)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, typeof (Page), control.ClientID, script, true);
    }
    else
    {
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(type, control.ClientID, script, true);
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Need your complete block of code, the above is incomplete. Cant see where </asp:ConfirmLinkButton> opens for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Page.IsAsyncPostBack
```

[**Page**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) class has a property: [**Page.IsPostBack**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx). you should not use `()` to access a property of any class. This is the reason you are getting this error.

Comment: can you tell us, which name-space is this class from:` WebControlUtils`

Comment: Asad Butt exactly. namespace WebControlUtils

Comment: hmm i need (), maybe do you have any other idea?

Comment: I really am confused about this `WebControlUtils` class. would be great and very helpful to check, if you can pass me a link for it's documentation on line

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a control named 'ConfirmButton' in the local namespace. You should rename this control, since that identifier is already used as a namespace name.

Comment: It's trying to cast an item to type `ConfirmButton.Controls.ConfirmLinkButton`, so you have a root namespace with the name `ConfirmButton` and a control with the identifier `ConfirmButton`. You shouldn't use a namespace name as the identifier for an object or you will run into problems like this.